# children nested extract data without tags or attributes

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I can not extract with vba scraping data individually from a site

[link to site soccer rating](http://www.soccer-rating.com/Manchester-City/220/)

```
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
   <td class="nomobil">30</td>
   <td>
     12.01.19
     <div class="ismobil">UK3</div>
   </td>
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
</tr>
```

inserting my code I extract both the date and the championship code

```
Dim objIE As Object
Dim itemEle As Object
dim td as Object
dim i as integer

Set objIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "http://www.soccer-rating.com/Manchester-City/220/"
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Set itemEle = objIE.document.getElementsByclassname("bigtable")(4)
i = 0
For Each td In itemEle.getElementsBytagname("tr")
  If i > 0 Then

    cells(i , 1) = td.getElementsBytagname("td")(1).Children(0).innertext
  end if
  i = i + 1
next td
```

in the first cell i found only championship code instead of the date

if I took the baby off (0) I would have this:

```
Cells(1, 1) = td.getElementsBytagname("td")(1).innertext
```

and I find myself in the cell (i, 1)

[image]

Comment: What is the expected result please?

Comment: Only date without code champiobship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get just the date with the following:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetDate()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://www.soccer-rating.com/Manchester-City/220/"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Debug.Print Split(.Document.querySelector(".bigtable:nth-of-type(3) .bigtable tr:nth-of-type(1) td").innerText, Chr$(32))(0)
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

With xmlhttp request and no browser

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.soccer-rating.com/Manchester-City/220/", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Debug.Print Split(html.getElementsByClassName("bigtable")(3).getElementsByTagName("TD")(0).innerText, Chr$(32))(0)
End Sub
```

---

Requires references to `Microsoft Internet Controls` and `Microsoft HTML Object Library`

Comment: thanks, you've got my mind, I just used the split with character separator ascii "enter", ie Chr $ (13)

Answer (score 0):

anyway I solved that

> cells(i , 1) = split(td.getElementsBytagname("td")(1).Children(0).innertext,Chr$(13))(1)

where

> Chr$(13)

is "enter" in ASCII code